# have issue in getting proper responce from for-loop

Tags: android, json, for-loop, response

> I am getting data from Json using For-loop.  here is my code:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(strri);
        Privacy_Setting_Ozone_Feed  obj=new Privacy_Setting_Ozone_Feed();
        jsonArray=jsonObj.getJSONArray("Setting");
        JSONArray jsonArray4=jsonObj.getJSONArray("blocklist");
        Log.d("ads", jsonArray4.toString());



        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)

        {
            JSONObject jsonInnerObj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


            try
            {
            obj.strvalue=jsonInnerObj.getString("value");
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

            try
            {
                obj.str_name=jsonInnerObj.getString("name");

            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        for (int j=0; j<jsonArray4.length(); j++)//----------(loop)
        {
            JSONObject jObject = jsonArray4.getJSONObject(j);

            try
            {
                obj.str_image=jObject.getString("image");

                Log.d("sadsa", obj.str_image);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            try
            {
                obj.str_blockname=jObject.getString("name");

                Log.d("test", obj.str_blockname);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

            arr.add(obj); //-------------------(1)
        }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return arr;//--------------(2)

}
```

> At this place arr.add(obj); I am geting the exact value from json,
>   Like if there are three different values so I am getting proper three
>   values... But at the return point, I am getting only last value that
>   is coming from the json loop.  please let me know that what mistake I
>   am doing here.

Comment: Where is all of your code? Where is `arr` defined? Don't use `try/catches` all over the place, it makes your code difficult to read.

Comment: Can you post your JSON data.?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `obj` object only once, because of only one reference you are modifying results in having same value in all entry. try calling constructor in for loop. It will solve you problem.